# Problem with itemize (related probably with the font)

Tags: fonts, itemize

I face a problem with the command "itemize". I write normally the command but there are 2 warnings in my MakeTeX compiler:

1. `` Font shape `OMS/udidot/m/n' undefined, using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead for symbol `textbullet' ``
2. `Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted`

I should inform you that the similar command "enumerate" is working normally.

Any help please?

My preamble is

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\newcolumntype{"}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 1pt\hskip\tabcolsep}}
\makeatother
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{udidot}

\begin{document}
\title{\Huge{asd}\\
\huge{asd}}
\author{\Large{asd}\\ asd}

\newcommand{\Ra}{\mathcal{R}}
\newcommand{\Rb}{\pazocal{R}}
\newcommand*\quot[2]{{^{\textstyle #1}\big/_{\textstyle #2}}}
\newtheorem{theo}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\newtheorem{defin}{Ορισμός}[section]
\newtheorem{prt}{Παρατήρηση}[section]
\newtheorem{prts}{Παρατηρήσεις}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Παράδειγμα}[section]
\newtheorem{exmps}{Παραδείγματα}[section]
\newtheorem{por}{Πόρισμα}[section]
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheo}{\textsc{Θεώρημα}}%
{colback=red!5,colframe=red!30!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myprop}{\textsc{Πρόταση}}%
{colback=blue!5,colframe=red!52!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mylm}{\textsc{Λήμμα}}%
{colback=blue!5,colframe=red!52!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mypor}{\textsc{Πόρισμα}}%
{colback=red!5,colframe=red!52!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\begin{itemize}
    \item We define the set $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,...\}.$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please make your MWE complete.

Comment: As daleif mentioned, there doesn't seem to be any `itemize` environment in your MWE, maybe you can add that so we can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you both for your  comments! But I dont understand what should I do... 1) What is MWE? A package? 2) How could I add itemize?

Comment: You MWE is far too long (most of this is irrelevant) try adding the `textcomp` package to gain access to text symbols.

Comment: @daleif Thank you. It works! Is MWE a set of packages? And if yes, is it bad to be long?

Comment: Just for your reference: A [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is the code that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see *compilable* code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Many of your code is irrelevant to your problem: For instance, the `\newcommand{\Ra}{\mathcal{R}}`. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for shortening your code.

Answer (score 3):

In order to access certain text symbols you'll often need the `textcomp` package. Which also solves the warning in this case. Note that it may choose a symbol from a different font if needed (as far as I know)